# The function exported by Emscripten cannot be imported

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I tried importing functions from `main.cpp` to `test.js`.

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

using namespace std;

int myfunc() {
    // Code
    return num;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

shell command:

```bash
./emcc main.c
```

This command generates two files, `a.out.wasm` and `a.out.js`.

I try to call `myfunc()` function in `test.js`

test.js:

```js
import { myFunc } from "a.out.js";

myFunc();
```

then run it:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'a.out.js' does not provide an export named 'myFunc'
```

When I checked the `a.out.js` file, I found that there was indeed no export statement。

Only this sentence is related to this function。

```js
var _myfunc = Module['_myfunc'] = createExportWrapper('myfunc');
```

How to solve this problem? How can I import the function into `test.js` ?